# How to check different condition for same row?

Tags: mysql

I have a row where I want to apply filter's to it. And I want to find for example every restaurant that has the category = 1 and 2. How can I apply this on My Sql query

This is my code (Only the were part) :

```
SELECT * From establishment WHERE `subcategories`.`id` = 1 AND `subcategories`.`id` = 21;
```

And the `query` is returning me empty. How can I do to have result's?

Here are my tables

```
Establishment
id
name


SubCategories
id
name


EstablishmentSubCategories

sub_category_id
establishment_id
```

Comment: Could you please share your two tables? The main mistake is that your where clause references the categories table. This won't work that way.

Comment: This is a more simplified version of the query. In fact I have 3 tables ( 1 middle table in the middle of restaurant's and categories

Comment: I can't do an AND but i don't want an "OR" i want something that fit's those keywords and just appears. I can put my tables no worries. Give me a second

Comment: answer updated @maio290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT establishment_id
FROM EstablishmentSubCategories
WHERE sub_category_id IN (1, 21)
GROUP BY establishment_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

returns the `establishment_id`s that you want, so you can use it with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM establishment 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT establishment_id
  FROM EstablishmentSubCategories
  WHERE sub_category_id IN (1, 21)
  GROUP BY establishment_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

Or with EXISTS:

```
SELECT e.* FROM establishment e
WHERE
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EstablishmentSubCategories c WHERE c.establishment_id = e.id AND sub_category_id = 1)
  AND 
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EstablishmentSubCategories c WHERE c.establishment_id = e.id AND sub_category_id = 21)
```

Comment: do I need the COUNT(*) = 2 ?

Comment: This makes sure that both categories exist for the same establishment. If you query for categories 1,21,31 yo should change to COUNT(*) = 3